# i can't run a function directly from VSCode, but the same can be run directly from Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

to run a function in VSCode i have to create an object and then print that object to get the output in console, but i can run it directly from a cell in jupyter notebook, i didn't integrate them , i've run them seperately

--------------Jupyter code--------------

```
def fun(x):
    return x + 2

fun(12)
```

Output

`14`

But if i want to print the same in Jupyter i have to create an Object and then print that object using print function

--------------VSCode code--------------

```
def fun(x):
return x + 2

a = fun(12)
print(a)
```

Output

`14`

Because if i try to run the function in the same way i run it in jupyter, it gives me blanks
e.g -

```
C:\Users\prati\PythonVsCode>
```

do i have to download a plugin for this function to work?? canuse i can't find anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter is based on [IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which by default prints the result of the last expression.

This is not standard behavior for the Python interpreter. You have to print manually. You don't need an extra variable though:

```
print(fun(12))
```

Note that the above code should work in Jupyter/IPython as well.

Comment: 1.) What does it mean by "prints the result of the last expression", does it mean, it will just print, as it is the default function? When the cell is executed 
2.) Thanks for the suggestions Much appreciated!!

Comment: Like the "I" in IPython suggests, it is designed for interactive use. So when you write an expression, its default behavior will be to print the result to the console (I don't exactly get what you mean with "default function"). If there are several expressions in your cell, by default, only the last one is printed, this behavior can be changed though. In standard Python you explicitly choose what is to be printed to the console with the `print` statement.